# Void pointer in a function with ctypes

Tags: python, c++, hook, ctypes

I need to use [minHook.dll](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra) for my project.
The example provided seems straightforward, but I cannot get it to work.
I don't understand this part:

```
MESSAGEBOXW fpMessageBoxW = NULL;

// Create a hook for MessageBoxW, in disabled state.
if (MH_CreateHook(&MessageBoxW, &DetourMessageBoxW, 
    reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&fpMessageBoxW)) != MH_OK)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Here's my Python code (adapted for the function I need to hook):

```
def _callback_pointer(handler):
    """Create and return C-pointer"""
    print('handler=',cmp_func(handler))
    return cmp_func(handler)

def callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    res = windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(*args, **kwargs)
    print(res)
    return res
cmp_func = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, wintypes.HINSTANCE, POINTER(c_void_p))
hinstDLL = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('Gdi32')._handle
hkprcSysMsg = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "TextOutW".encode(encoding='ascii'))
minHook = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib/minHook.dll')
minHook.MH_Initialize()
orig_fp = None
minHook.MH_CreateHook(hkprcSysMsg, _callback_pointer(callback), byref(orig_fp))
```

It ends up with an error:

> TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'NoneType'

What should I do to at least make `MH_CreateHook` return `1`?

**UPDATE:** Here is `MH_CreateHook` signature:

```
MH_STATUS WINAPI MH_CreateHook(LPVOID pTarget, LPVOID pDetour, LPVOID *ppOriginal)
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward: `byref` wants an argument that isn't `None`.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref) are pretty clear on this point: "must be an instance of a ctypes type".  `None` is not an instance of a ctypes type.

Comment: If it was straightforward, I would guess what I should put there instead of byref. What does it expect?

Comment: Add `MH_CreateHook`'s signature. And also always specify which line of code generates an error (even though in this case it's obvious). Also try to avoid having "undefined" stuff like `cmp_func` (This is also known as [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Try passing `None` (without `byref`) or `POINTER(c_long)()` directly.

Comment: @101 this doesn't work.
    hook = minHook.MH_CreateHook(hkprcSysMsg, _callback_pointer(callback), POINTER(c_long)())
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (12 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention